# Dynamically reload elements and read their new attributes in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout, dynamic-loading

I have an Ajax call that returns a piece of html code that is supposed to replace old html code on the page, giving them new attributes. After I successfully dynamically change my elements, I want to run another piece of JS code that reads and uses some of the attributes of the dynamically reloaded elements. However, JS prefers to read the old data (as if it's running synchronously).

The only workaround I've found is to set a timer, but the timer's delay time has to be relatively high (300 ms) to guarantee that it's always done correctly. What is the right way to do this?

Here is a pseudo-code for what I have right now. It works but the 300ms delay time is terrible.

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( newCode ) {
    $("#myDynamicDiv").html(newCode);
    setTimeout(function(){
        //Use the data that was just stored in #myDynamicDiv
    },300);
});
```

Comment: I do this all the time, and it works perfectly, maybe its the ajax cache messing you about, i always turn it off, there is a global setting for it. obviously make sure your JS that is reading the attributes is inside the post function and below the html insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me I use `.promise().done()` may be it'll work with you

```
$("#myDynamicDiv").html(newCode).promise().done(function(){
  // your code here
});
```

**Edit**: To someone who'll comes here later ..While my code isn't working with [Mohasen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432116/mohsen) he find a solution himself .. [**Please find his answer below**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44277317/3385827)

Comment: That doesn't exactly work, at least in my case, but I'm looking at "done" and "promise" to see if there's something for me there. I'll tell you as soon as I get it to work!

Comment: OK I got it to work using "then" and Deferred objects. I accepted your answer because it put me in the right track. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Mohsen you can add it to my answer with the right code with your name [Update by Mohsen and the right answer]  may be it will help someone on the future .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: @Mohsen please post your solution too I think it would be helpful for other more than the answer you have marked as accepted

Comment: OK, submitted it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted Mohamed-Yousef's answer, but since that did not include the full answer, here is the full version of what I eventually did:

A JQuery ajax call always returns a "Deferred" object when it's called. You can use this object's "then()" method to run things after the ajax call is finished. Here is the code:

```
dfrd = $.post( "ajax/test.html", function( newCode ) {
    $("#myDynamicDiv").html(newCode);
});

dfrd.then(function(){
    //Anything that is here is guaranteed to happen after the Ajax call is done.
});
```

Comment: I gave you +1 for this answer and pointed to it in my answer .. Have a great day :-)